# Windows Phone 8.1 Adaptive app for all resolutions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I hope this wasn't asked before, I couldn't find an easy solution everywhere...
I'm developing a simple windows phone 8.1 soundboard but if the resolutions are bigger than VXGA the grid and the buttons are too small and wrong placed. I read this: [Taking Advantage of Large-Screen Windows Phones](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/22/taking-advantage-of-large-screen-windows-phones/)
  but I did not understand well.

Does anyone knows how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement to your xaml visual states. Those visual states have adaptive triggers (like display resolution) and setters (for example setting your button height to 50 if the adaptive trigger fires).
 Just like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="VisualStates.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:VisualStates"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"></AdaptiveTrigger>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="AdaptiveButton.Width" Value="80"></Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Button x:Name="AdaptiveButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="0">Test</Button>
</Grid>
```

Without the Visual State the Adaptive Button would have the Width of 0 but because of the Visual State its getting set up to 80. 
Of course this is a not practical example and you should use blend for visual studio because it even gives you an ui for simply implementing those visual states. But before you practice you should google "visualstatemanager class" and search for more examples.
**EDIT:**
You can also for example check the window width and height in the **pageloaded** method and then for example change the properties like:

```
double displaywidth = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
if(displaywidth >= 300) {}//set local variable display width and than do sth
```

Comment: Thanks you so much :)